# How to cast and write back into a nested column

Tags: apache-drill

I have a nested json data file. I need to write to Parquet with specific numeric data types. So need to control some fields being Integer, some being Long etc. I can cast the columns, but cannot write them back to the nested location. The data must be in the nested structure.

Here is what I tried:

`` CREATE TABLE cdg.`test2.parquet` AS SELECT CAST(t.l1.l2.id AS INTEGER) l1.l2.id FROM cdg.`data.json` t; ``

The error I get is `Error: PARSE ERROR: Encountered "."` on the path after the closing bracket of the CAST statement. 

`AS INTEGER) l1.l2.id FROM c
              ^`

Analysis #1: If I do not put in that nested field it writes the expression result out fine:

`+---------+
| EXPR$0  |
+---------+
| 22222   |
| 22222   |
| 22222   |
| 22222   |`

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is complaining that you cannot specify a field name l1.l2.id as alias to the cast expression. Alias should be a top level field.

Alias can be provided to a column with  as  or without using 'as' keyword (implicitly parser assumes as)

So for example if you want to name a the resultant expression of the cast expression aId then the following Sql statement can be used.

CREATE TABLE cdg.`test2.parquet` AS SELECT CAST(t.l1.l2.id AS INTEGER) as Id FROM cdg.`data.json` t;

Hope this helps.